# Web Service with Factory Pattern. c#

Tags: c#, web-services, factory-pattern

I have the following service:

```
  class SalesChannelService
{

    private static readonly ILog log = Logger.GetLog(typeof(SalesChannelService));
    protected readonly ProgressManager _progressManager;
    private readonly  ISalesChannelService _salesChannelService;


    public SalesChannelService(SalesChannelServiceFactory.SalesChannelServiceType salesChannel)
    {
        _salesChannelService = SalesChannelServiceFactory.GetSalesChannelService(salesChannel);
    }


    public IList<Order> GetSalesChannelOrders()
    {
        return _salesChannelService.GetSalesChannelOrders();    
    }

}
```

Do you think this is the correct approach instead of of creating multiple SalesChannelServices for each implementation of the ISalesChannelService?

Or is there some other pattern that suits this?

Thanks
Neil

Comment: SalesChannelServiceType  is an enum that is used to switch on the SalesChannel implementations in the SalesChannelServiceFactory..

Comment: For what it's worth this looks fine to me. In my opinion no need to complicate it.

Comment: I think in this way, all new implementatinos of the interface will result in no need to alter the service layer but will also give flexibility on client side for retrieving different services.